# Current line number keeps to be 0 no matter where cursor is

Tags: macos, vi

Please see the attached to images.

When I change the line the line numbers changes, so that the cursor's line number is always 0, the previous and next line numbers are always 1.

Is it a bug?

OS: Yosemite.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have line numbering set to relative.  Absolute line numbers will count the more traditional way from the top of the file.

Comment: I have commented out:
"if exists("&relativenumber")
"       set relativenumber
"       au BufReadPost * set relativenumber
"endif